# I have no idea why this java code doesn't work

Tags: java, operators

Ok SO I made an escape the room program and the boolean for light doesn't work

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("Welcome To The Hogwarts Escape Room");
  System.out.println("To Play The Hogwarts Escape Room Press Y");
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  String useranswer = sc.nextLine();
  boolean light = false;
// This is not my entire code but the part that was necessary. 
  System.out.println("Press U to look up");
useranswer = sc.nextLine();
if (usernaswer.equals("U"){
System.out.println(" You look above you and see nothing as the ceiling is too dark to see in.");
    System.out.println("Would you like to: \n Look Closer press A \n Return To Your Original Position press B");
    useranswer = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(light);
// this part doesn't work.. I checked and made sure the useranswer was A and the boolean does equal to false.
    if (useranswer.equals("A")&&(light = false)){
      ceilingCloserlightFalse(sc, useranswer, inventory, light);
    }
    else if (useranswer.equals("B")){
      original(sc, useranswer, inventory, light);
    }
// this was the setup to the constructor

public static void ceilingCloserlightFalse(Scanner sc, String useranswer, String [] inventory, boolean light){
    System.out.println("You go closer and see something faintly but cant tell what it is without a light");
    System.out.println("You returned to the original position because there was nothing else to do there.");
    original(sc, useranswer, inventory, light);
    
  }
    
  }
}
```

Ok So I wonder if I am doing something wrong with the method or the && operator. I checked to make sure that useranswer was a and I also checked to make sure that

Comment: `light = false` you probably mean `==`. Also, `usernaswer` looks like a typo. It's hard to say why it doesn't work because you've not said what it should do, nor what it does instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are *assigning* false to the variable, not comparing it:

```
if (useranswer.equals("A")&&(light = false)){
      ceilingCloserlightFalse(sc, useranswer, inventory, light);
    }
```

You want to use `==`, not `=`. Also, consider that useranswer might be null, so you should be doing `"A".equals(useranswer)` to avoid a NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

Some developers use Yoda speak to avoid the common mistake we have here.

Instead of:

```
if (useranswer.equals("A")&&(light = false)){
      ceilingCloserlightFalse(sc, useranswer, inventory, light);
}
```

Write your comparison backward like

```
if (useranswer.equals("A")&&(false = light)){
      ceilingCloserlightFalse(sc, useranswer, inventory, light);
}
```

Then you'd get a compiler error pointing you to the fact you're using `=` instead of `==`.